# ical file containing multiple events doesn't import (single event works fine)

Tags: icalendar

I am trying (and failing) to import an ics file that contains multiple events. When I include just one event the import works (I'm using iCal). As soon as a second event is there it fails.

Each event is enclosed in BEGIN:VEVENT...END:VEVENT tags.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this ics file?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Foobar Foobar//NONSGML Foobar Foobar//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:PBSTI000000000017Z@foobar.com
DTSTAMP:20111210T161211Z
DTSTART:20111210T210000Z
DTEND:20111210T230000Z
TRANSP: TRANSPARENT
SUMMARY:Foobar - foobar
DESCRIPTION:Foobar - foobar
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:PBSTI000000003246Z@foobar.com
DTSTAMP:20110824T161211Z
DTSTART:20110824T170000Z
DTEND:20110824T170000Z
TRANSP: TRANSPARENT
SUMMARY:Foobar - foobar
DESCRIPTION:Foobar - foobar
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found my issue... Hope this helps others!
Instead of... METHOD:REQUEST , I needed to use METHOD:PUBLISH

Comment: Also helps to use test events in the future if just testing loading (not history) - makes them easier to see.  For moment I thought was just that the old one was not being imported.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a file with multiple events, and it will work fine if users explicitly import it (through File->Open->Import), but double-clicking imports only the first event.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, plus this question is 2 years old and the asker found his solution long ago.

Comment: @OGHaza I ran into the same problem years ago (like 7)...if You have multiple events in one .ics file You have to import it instead of just doubleclick. The fact that the METHOD:PUBLISH is required is true, but even if it should have been there in the first place only the first appointment seems to be saved when doubleclicking. Therefore an import is required. At least in Outlook.