# Mac Calendar not importing all events from ics file

Tags: macos, icalendar

I have a .ics file with properly formatted (validated) data, containing 2 events. When I try to import it into the Calendar application on MacOS, it only imports the second event, and ignores the first one. I saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319183/ical-file-containing-multiple-events-doesnt-import-single-event-works-fine) but it doesn't quite address the question

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
PRODID:-//Cal's Bridge Club//Calvin Calhoun//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:4696563918045184@m.com
ORGANIZER;CN=Calvin Calhoun:MAILTO:cal@m.com
DTSTAMP:20160215T142555Z
DTSTART:20160201T213000Z
DTEND:20160201T235500Z
SUMMARY:Night guys
TRANSP: TRANSPARENT
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:4696563918045184@m.com
ORGANIZER;CN=Calvin Calhoun:MAILTO:cal@m.com
DTSTAMP:20160215T142555Z
DTSTART:20160229T213000Z
DTEND:20160229T235500Z
SUMMARY:Night guys
TRANSP: TRANSPARENT
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UID of both events is the same, which may be causing problems.  Each event should have a unique UID.

Also, there is a space after the colon character in the TRANSP property, which shouldn't be there.  This may cause problems too.